# DjangoModelForm: How to add extra fields and preprocess them before sending to views

Tags: django, modelform

I have a model form which displays all the fields:

```
class BatchForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('__all__')
```

It works fine and shows all the fields in the views.
I now want to add extra fields to this form which dont exist in the model. 
These fields are:

```
completed_tasks: int
statistics: array
```

I then want to add 2 methods in the form which auto populate these fields before sending it to the view. The methods will be:

```
def completed_tasks_method(self, obj):
    return obj.assignments_per_task * obj.total_tasks()

def statistics_method(self, obj):
    #something
```

i cant figure out how to extend the modelform to add additional attributes and then how to populate the fields before sending them to the views.
Can you please help ? Thanks.

Comment: share your views.py please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fields in the model from and manipulate provide it initial values.

```
class BatchForm(ModelForm):
    completed_tasks = forms.IntegerField()
    statistics = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
    # or whateer fields you want to use
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('__all__')
```

in views

```
form = BatchForm(initial={'completed_tasks', <VALUE>, 'statistics': <VALUE>})
```

Or if you want to do it with methods, you can do

```
class BatchForm(ModelForm):
    completed_tasks = forms.IntegerField()
    statistics = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
    # or whateer fields you want to use
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.initial['completed_tasks'] = self.completed_tasks_method(self.instance)
            self.initial['statistics'] = self.statistics_method(self.instance)

    def completed_tasks_method(self, obj):
        return obj.assignments_per_task * obj.total_tasks()

    def statistics_method(self, obj):
        # something
```